# Mosaicplot with ggplot2 too small

Tags: r, ggplot2, mosaic-plot

I'm trying to visualize a mosaic plot with ggplot2 and ggmosaic. I'm having the problem that the mosaicplot itself is really small and the legend too big. Do you have an idea of how can I arrange this?

The code I'm using is the following:

## Create a mosaic plot

```
mosaic_plot_color <- ggplot(data = longdata) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(Category, variable), fill=Category ,weight = `value`), offset=0.010) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 2)+
  #scale_color_brewer(palette=3)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = .5), 
        legend.key.height = unit(.1, 'cm'), 
        legend.key.width = unit(.4, 'cm'))+
  labs(x ="Frequency of social contact" , y = "Type of street (microm)", weight = "Number of observations", title = "Social contact with locals living in different house typologies")
```

[image: Mosaic Plot Output]

**Reproducible data:**
*The **dput output** from my data is the following:*

```
structure(list(Category = c("1-2 family houses in homogeneously built street section", 
"1-2 family houses in non-homogeneous street section", "3-5 family houses", 
"6-9 family houses", "Blocks with 10-19 households", "High-rise buildings with 20 and more households", 
"Predominantly commercially used houses", "1-2 family houses in homogeneously built street section", 
"1-2 family houses in non-homogeneous street section", "3-5 family houses", 
"6-9 family houses", "Blocks with 10-19 households", "High-rise buildings with 20 and more households", 
"Predominantly commercially used houses", "1-2 family houses in homogeneously built street section", 
"1-2 family houses in non-homogeneous street section", "3-5 family houses", 
"6-9 family houses", "Blocks with 10-19 households", "High-rise buildings with 20 and more households", 
"Predominantly commercially used houses", "1-2 family houses in homogeneously built street section", 
"1-2 family houses in non-homogeneous street section", "3-5 family houses", 
"6-9 family houses", "Blocks with 10-19 households", "High-rise buildings with 20 and more households", 
"Predominantly commercially used houses", "1-2 family houses in homogeneously built street section", 
"1-2 family houses in non-homogeneous street section", "3-5 family houses", 
"6-9 family houses", "Blocks with 10-19 households", "High-rise buildings with 20 and more households", 
"Predominantly commercially used houses", "1-2 family houses in homogeneously built street section", 
"1-2 family houses in non-homogeneous street section", "3-5 family houses", 
"6-9 family houses", "Blocks with 10-19 households", "High-rise buildings with 20 and more households", 
"Predominantly commercially used houses"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("Never", "Rarely", 
"Every month", "Every Week", "More than once a week", "Daily"
), class = "factor"), value = c(0, 24, 11, 35, 11, 14, 0, 4, 
26, 34, 28, 20, 20, 8, 6, 24, 22, 39, 14, 13, 3, 14, 40, 59, 
54, 48, 14, 6, 1, 26, 46, 36, 37, 17, 4, 4, 42, 52, 63, 40, 13, 
0)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried scaling the Legend with the following part of the code expecting that the mosaic plot would change the size, but did not work as I expected.

```
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = .5), 
        **legend.key.height = unit(.1, 'cm'), 
        legend.key.width = unit(.4, 'cm'))**+
```

I would like to reach something like this, just with colors like I have in the first image:
[MosaicPlotrightscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwPEp.png)

I would appreciate any hints from your side.
Many thanks in advance,
Victoria

---

**To whom might be interested:
I could reach my objective and this is how the code looks like:**

```
ggplot(data=longdata)+
  geom_mosaic(aes(x=product(variable,Category), fill=Category,weight = `value`))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=4, angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=5, angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette=2)
```

The plot looks like this:
[Finalplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4nXI.png)

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten is this more understandable? Thanks in advance, V

Comment: If you click on the zoom button in Rstudio, you will see the plot is scaled better.

Comment: Hi @Quinten, no, it is not.

Comment: Are you sure you used the zoom button and opened it to full screen?

Comment: Yes, and it is anyway very thin and not representative of what I'm trying to show. The bars look all the same, while normally in mosaicplot one can see that the width depends on the ammount of observations for each x category as it does on the y axis.

Comment: To whom might be interested: I could reach my objective and this is how the code looks like: ``` ggplot(data=longdata)+ geom_mosaic(aes(x=product(variable,Category), fill=Category,weight = value))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=4, angle = 45, hjust = 1))+ theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=5, angle = 45, hjust = 1))+ scale_fill_brewer(palette=2) ``` –

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to `str_wrap` your long variable names:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmosaic)

longdata |>
  mutate(Category = str_wrap(Category, 30)) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_mosaic(aes(
    x = product(Category, variable),
    fill = Category ,
    weight = `value`
  ), offset = 0.010) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 2) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      angle = 45,
      hjust = 1,
      vjust = 1
    ),
    legend.key.height = unit(0.8, 'cm'),
    legend.key.width = unit(.4, 'cm')
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Frequency of social contact" ,
    y = "Type of street (microm)",
    weight = "Number of observations",
    title = "Social contact with locals living in different house typologies"
  )
```

[image]